# Data Grid View Combobox

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using entity framework 4 and Csharp.  I have a datagridview in a windows form.  The datagridview has a colomn with a combobox.  The combobox is to hold an Entity object.

Usually I do the following:

dataGridViewComboboxColumn.DisplayMember = "DisplayThis"
dataGridViewComboboxColumn.ValueMember = "DisplayThisId"

But I want:

dataGridViewComboboxColumn.ValueMember = Entity

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...I needed to add foreign key properties to my entity in the model.edmx.